# CSS :hover div elements

Tags: html, css, hover, element

My css:
`.sec-hover :hover {background:pink;}`

My div:`<div class="sec-hover"><h2>heading</h2><p>paragraph</p></div>`

With this code, the whole div does not hover in pink. On hover the h2 and p elements hover pink separately.  How do I get the whole div to hover pink?

codepen: [1]: http://codepen.io/cboy/pen/GWgOGa

Answer (score 5):

No space before colon : , Try this :

```
.sec-hover:hover{
background: pink 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-color`

```css
.sec-hover:hover{
background-color: pink 
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-hover"><h2>heading</h2><p>paragraph</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ! Used proper syntax `;`

```css
.sec-hover:hover{
background:pink;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-hover">
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```